# Fisher exact test for enrichment of subpopulations in single cell data

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, fishers-exact-test

We have single cell data from 12 control and 12 diseased individuals.  The data has been integrated (remove batch effects) and clustered.  We would like to know if there are any clusters that are enriched/depleted in disease versus control.

I read a paper that said they accomplished this using the fisher exact test.  They also had single cell data from multiple donor samples. I do not think this is the best way of doing this.  The fisher exact test assumes independence of observations in the contingency table.  Because the cells are associated with 24 sample IDs, I do not believe they can be called independent.

I think a better test would be to calculate the cluster proportions of each sample, and perform the wilcoxon rank sum test for each cluster.  This has been done in multiple papers, and it accounts for differences in cluster composition across donors. Please help me understand if I am wrong.